# Npm run start giving an error of "Cannot determine project or target for command" after angular version upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

When I am running command `npm run start`, I am getting an error of `Cannot determine project or target for command` after angular version upgrade from 13 to 17.
I followed angular guideline to upgrade the angular project but now I am not able to run application. Below are my package.json and angular.json files.

Can someone point out what I am missing and how can I run `npm run start` successful.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "test-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build:lib": "ng build test-angular --configuration production",
    "watch:lib": "ng build test-angular --watch",
    "pack:lib": "npm run build:lib && cd dist/test-angular && npm pack",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.7",
    "@angular/language-service": "^17.0.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "4.0.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.7.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^17.0.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

**angular.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "test-angular": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/test-angular",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/test-angular/src",
      "prefix": "css",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/test-angular/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/test-angular/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/test-angular/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/test-angular/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/test-angular/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/test-angular/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/test-angular/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/test-angular/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try ng serve?

Comment: Yes, I ran that command. It seems issue with application type to me. But I am not sure. Is it possible to run command on this application type?

Comment: @DevangPatel please run `npm run start` in the same location as `package.json` one more thing you can try is to check these properties, with a default angular project you can create using `ng new` the properties are `
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",`